# How to create a list of list from the given input?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have an input list

```
input_list = [[278, 207], [695, 205], [672, 205], [325, 205], [302, 205],[650, 167], [556, 167], [533, 167]]
```

I need an output list like these two

```
output_list_1 = [[278, 205], [695, 205], [672, 205], [325, 205], [302,205]]

output_list_2 = [[650, 167], [556, 167], [533, 167]]
```

I want to compare all the second value of each sublist and if the difference between them is more than 2 I create a new list. So I have multiple lists of one list.
All the second value gets averaged.

Comment: Have you tried anything? SO is not a homework service.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a list of lists, which would be better than dynamicaly making new list names.

Something like this:

```
input_list = [[278, 207], [695, 205], [672, 205], [325, 205], [302, 205],[650, 167], [556, 167], [533, 167]]

output_list = [[input_list[0]]] # Create an output list, with the first element of input_list as a list of lists. 
x = 0
for i in range(1, len(input_list)):
    if abs(input_list[i-1][1]- input_list[i][1]) > 2: # Check if absolute difference > 2
        x += 1
        output_list.append([]) # Create new sublist
    output_list[x].append(input_list[i]) # append sublist to output_list

print(output_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dic={}
input_list = [[278, 207], [695, 205], [672, 205], [325, 205], [302, 205],[650, 167], [556, 167], [533, 167]]
data =  list(set([i[1] for i in input_list]))
for i in data :
    dic[i]=[]

for  i in input_list :
    dic[i[1]].append(i[0])

new_l =[]
result =[]
for k,v in dic.items():
    for i in v:
        new_l.append([i,k])
    if len(new_l)>2:
        result.append(new_l)
    new_l=[]
print(result)


#output [[[650, 167], [556, 167], [533, 167]],[[695, 205], [672, 205], [325, 205], [302, 205]]]
```

Comment: Your output creates a separate sublist for `[278, 207]`. That's not what was requested (difference > 2).

Comment: @NielsHenkens thanks for correcting. solution updated

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `slice_when` method:

```
def slice_when(predicate, iterable):
  i, x, size = 0, 0, len(iterable)
  while i < size-1:
    if predicate(iterable[i], iterable[i+1]):
      yield iterable[x:i+1]
      x = i + 1
    i += 1
  yield iterable[x:size]
```

Callable on your `input_list` with the required condition (`lambda`):

```
slices = slice_when(lambda x,y: abs(x[1] - y[1]) > 2, input_list)
print(list(slices))
#=> [[[278, 207], [695, 205], [672, 205], [325, 205], [302, 205]], [[650, 167], [556, 167], [533, 167]]]
```